How to Test EclipseStore with EmbeddedStorageManager in Spring Boot?
I'm working on a Java 21, Spring Boot 3.3 application using Vaadin 24 and EclipseStore 1.4.0 for embedded storage. I'm having trouble setting up a simple test to ensure that I can read and write to the database using EclipseStore.
In production, my setup works fine, but I'm struggling to get tests working. I want to test my repository class (EclipseProjectAdapter) that interacts with EclipseStore's EmbeddedStorageManager. For my test, I want to use an in-memory storage or a temporary database to avoid interacting with my production database.
Here's what I've tried so far:
Test class:
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
@Tag("database")
class EclipseProjectAdapterTest {
    @Autowired
    EmbeddedStorageManager storageManager;
    EclipseProjectAdapter adapter;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        storageManager.start();
        storageManager.setRoot(new DataRoot());
        adapter = new EclipseProjectAdapter(storageManager);
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        storageManager.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    void canReadAndWrite() {
        List<Project> projects = adapter.findAll();
        assertThat(projects).isEmpty();

        Project project = Project.create("Project A");
        adapter.save(project);
        List<Project> allProjects = adapter.findAll();
        assertThat(allProjects).hasSize(1);
        assertThat(allProjects.getFirst().name()).isEqualTo("Project A");
    }
}

Test configuration:
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    EmbeddedStorageManager inMemoryStorageManager(
            @Autowired EclipseStoreProperties myConfiguration,
            @Autowired EmbeddedStorageManagerFactory managerFactory,
            @Autowired EmbeddedStorageFoundationFactory foundationFactory) {

        String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/test-store-" + UUID.randomUUID();
        myConfiguration.setStorageDirectory(tempDir);
        EmbeddedStorageFoundation<?> storageFoundation = foundationFactory.createStorageFoundation(myConfiguration);

        return managerFactory.createStorage(storageFoundation, false);
    }
}

test/resources/application.properties
org.eclipse.store.storage-directory=${java.io.tmpdir}/${random.int}
Error message:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.configuration.EclipseStoreProperties' 
available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

What I've Tried:

Including the eclipsestore-spring-boot-starter dependency in my pom.xml.
Explicitly defining the EclipseStoreProperties, EmbeddedStorageManagerFactory, and EmbeddedStorageFoundationFactory beans in my TestConfig.
Verifying that the auto-configuration of EclipseStore is enabled.
Checking that my test profile and properties are correctly set to use a temporary directory for storage.

Despite these efforts, I keep running into issues with missing beans like EmbeddedStorageManagerFactory and EclipseStoreProperties. I'm not sure how to properly configure a test environment for EclipseStore.
Questions:

How can I configure my Spring Boot test to use an in-memory or temporary storage with EclipseStore?
Is there a way to use TestContainers or a similar approach with EclipseStore for testing purposes?
Are there any best practices or examples for testing with EclipseStore that could help resolve these issues?

Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated!

The easiest way:
public class SampleEclipseStoreTest
{

    @TempDir
    Path location;

    @Test
    void saveAndLoadTest()
    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Hello");
        list.add("World");

        try (EmbeddedStorageManager storageManager = EmbeddedStorage.start(list, location)) {
        }

        try (EmbeddedStorageManager storageManager = EmbeddedStorage.start(location)) {
            List<String> loaded = (List<String>) storageManager.root();
            assertIterableEquals(list, loaded);
        }
    }
}

Eclipse-store is autoclosable.
Junit has an annotation @TempDir. The files are removed after test.

I'll try it. Thanks!

It works! Thanks again. I have also updated my answer below based on your suggestions.

Zdenek, any idea why I had to use the eager storer in my answer below? I have not been able to get this test to pass while using the normal lazy store() method.

Ok, I finally understand. https://github.com/eclipse-store/store/issues/295

Moving the storage manager setup inside of the test seems to have solved it. I also removed the test/resources/application.properties file since it doesn't seem necessary.
@Tag("database")
class EclipseProjectAdapterTest {

    private EclipseProjectAdapter adapter;
    @TempDir
    Path storageDir;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EclipseProjectAdapterTest.class);

    @Test
    void canWriteReadRestartAndReadAgain() {
        writeData();
        log.info("Storage manager shut down. Restarting...");

        readData();
    }

    private void writeData() {
        try (EmbeddedStorageManager storageManager = startStorageManager()) {
            adapter = new EclipseProjectAdapter(storageManager);
            List<Project> projects = adapter.findAll();
            assertThat(projects).isEmpty();

            Project project = Project.create("Project A");
            adapter.save(project);

            List<Project> allProjects = adapter.findAll();
            assertThat(allProjects).hasSize(1);
            assertThat(allProjects.getFirst().name()).isEqualTo("Project A");
        }
    }

    private void readData() {
        try (EmbeddedStorageManager storageManager = startStorageManager()) {
            adapter = new EclipseProjectAdapter(storageManager);

            List<Project> allProjects = adapter.findAll();
            assertThat(allProjects).hasSize(1);
            assertThat(allProjects.getFirst().name()).isEqualTo("Project A");
        }
    }

    private EmbeddedStorageManager startStorageManager() {
        return EmbeddedStorage.start(storageDir);
    }

public class EclipseProjectAdapter implements ProjectRepository {
    private final EmbeddedStorageManager storageManager;

    public EclipseProjectAdapter(EmbeddedStorageManager storageManager) {
        this.storageManager = storageManager;
        initializeRoot();
    }

    private void initializeRoot() {
        if (storageManager.root() == null) {
            storageManager.setRoot(new DataRoot());
            storageManager.storeRoot();
        }
    }

    @Write
    @Override
    public void save(Project project) {
        DataRoot root = (DataRoot) storageManager.root();
        root.projects().add(project);
        saveWithEagerStoring(root);  // Use eager storer for at least this save operation to ensure persistence
    }

    @Read
    @Override
    public List<Project> findAll() {
        DataRoot root = (DataRoot) storageManager.root();
        return new ArrayList<>(root.projects().all());
    }

    @Read
    @Override
    public Optional<Project> findByName(String projectName) {
        List<String> allNames = findAllNames();
        String cleanedName = ProjectNameMatcher.from(projectName, allNames).orElse(null);
        if (cleanedName == null) return Optional.empty();
        DataRoot root = (DataRoot) storageManager.root();
        return Optional.ofNullable(root.projects().byName(projectName));
    }

    @Read
    @Override
    public List<String> findAllNames() {
        DataRoot root = (DataRoot) storageManager.root();
        return new ArrayList<>(root.projects().getAllNames());
    }

    private void saveWithEagerStoring(DataRoot root) {
        Storer eagerStorer = storageManager.createEagerStorer();
        eagerStorer.store(root);
        eagerStorer.commit();
    }
}

